# Multiple instances of same elements in a form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, form-submit

From the database, I load some data that user can edit.

Let's say we have this form:

```
<form>
Name: [TextBox]
Data: [TextArea]
-------------------
Name: [TextBox]
Data: [TextArea]
...
Name: [TextBox]
Data: [TextArea]
-------------------
[Submit Button]
</form>
```

What names should the elements have?

What is the best approach to fetch the posted data using PHP, so I can understand what's the id for each one?

Note: I want to have **only 1 submit button**!

Thanks...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With PHP you can use an array:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
Data: <textarea name="data[]"></textarea>
...
Name: <input type="text" name="name[]" value="">
Data: <textarea name="data[]"></textarea>
```

Then in PHP you can process it like this:

```
$nameArray = $_POST['name'];
$dataArray = $_POST['data'];
foreach($nameArray as $key => $name){
  $data = $dataArray[$key]);    
}
```

Another way is to use php to generate names. Make them look like this:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="name[0]" value="">
Data: <textarea name="data[0]"></textarea>
Name: <input type="text" name="name[1]" value="">
Data: <textarea name="data[1]"></textarea>
...
Name: <input type="text" name="name[10]" value="">
Data: <textarea name="data[10]"></textarea>
```

This way you can be sure that $_POST['name'][10] corresponds to $_POST['data'][10].

Comment: First snippet is good for creating new entries, second snippet - for editing existing entries.

Comment: I didn't know about this functionality of PHP! Thanks!!